# Chat.StackExchange Reputation Bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I was not able to chat due to a strange bug. It said I didn't have enough rep even though I have been chatting for a very long time now. I've supplied supporting images that show the error message, what Chat.SE thought my rep was, and what GD.SE (the parent account) says my rep is. I was able to resolve this issue by changing my parent account to a different SE site (SharePoint.SE in this exact case) and switching it back to GD.SE. I wanted to post the bug and supporting information just to raise awareness. My specific case has been resolved but if anyone does have insight on what happened, is it a known issue and a fix is in the works, etc. that would be great.

[image: Says I need 20 reputation to talk here.]
[image: What Chat.SE thinks my rep is]
[image: GD.SE reputation is 750! :D]

Comment: I'll just add that I did attempt to clear the cache, restart the browser (Chrome), and tried a different browser (Internet Explorer 9) all with the same results.

Comment: Try now. I have force-refreshed your chat profile.

Comment: It looks fine to me: http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/31059/todderslegrande

Comment: @NullUserException_: That's cos I used the refresh tool.

Comment: @Manishearth ... and it's back to 0 again.

Comment: @NullUserException_: ....and I fixed it again. Hopefully this doesn't continue :s Chat parent users have been acting weird today (there was another issue with another user)

Comment: Oh snap! Thanks for following up guys! You rock.